# React Material-UI how to save TextFields in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tsx

How can I save an input with Material-UI TextFields in Typescript. My idea was to have a default value in the TextField and with a button, it should save the new value from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use onChange for Textfields

```
onChange={(e)=>this.saveTextFields(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this, maybe without using "this."?